# Jscript runtime error trying to use jquery datatables in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, plugins

I'm getting the following error when I try to access a page that's supposed to display a table with the jquery plugin from datatables.net:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'

Here is where I'm referencing various scripts/plugins on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="Script/jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/supersubs.js"></script>
```

Here is where I'm trying to call the dataTable function on the table (with id mod123):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mods123').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

I have a thead and tbody tag within my table, but when I build the project and run it locally and navigate to the page, it gives me this error.  When I go to the page in different browser, the error doesn't show of course, but the table that I'm trying to affect is not changed in any way.

When I look at the page in Firebug, it gives me the following error: $("#mods123").dataTable is not a function

Chrome's debugger says "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your ID "mod123" or "mods123"? You used both in your post.

Comment: I put together [a barebones example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjDRd/1/) that seems to work just fine. Check your URLs, IDs, etc.

Comment: It's mods123, sorry, but it's that way in the selector as well as the table tag.  I just tried the datables debugger and it tells me that datatables isn't available on my page, despite my seeing the reference to it when I view source. Argh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your version of jQuery is not compatible with dataTables.  Try using the version of jQuery that came with dataTables.  I think it is jQuery 1.7.1.

Comment: I tried barebones examples down to jQuery 1.2.6 and they all worked, but I did not specifically try 1.6.2. Maybe there's a compatibility issue with that version.

Comment: Tried 1.7.1, and also tried the non-minified version of datatables, but nothing is working.

Comment: From the [dataTable's website](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5082/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-datatable/p1): "The error means that either the DataTables plug-in hasn't been loaded, jQuery has been loaded again (thus overwriting the old one) or $ is not jQuery."

Comment: @Levi Remove first jQuery reference and move jQuery tools script line above the dataTable script line. Sounds like jQuery($) might be getting loaded twice.  Once here:  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>  And another here: <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> if jQuery is included in the tools.

Comment: @PaulS, thanks, yeah, as you see below, I was able to get it working by removing jquery tools, but thanks for the tip, I had no idea that jquery was included IN jquery tools!  Your suggestion worked and now I don't have to deal with removing jquery tools...

Comment: @Levi When you are downloading jQuery tools there is an option to include jQuery.  That might solve your problem, but I haven't use jQuery tools just jQuery and jQuery UI with jQuery dataTables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well, it looks like it was actually a conflict between datatables and jquery tools.  When I removed the reference to jquery tools, it worked!

I don't think we're currently using jquery tools, so I may be ok, but if not, how can I avoid this conflict?  I couldn't find a reference to this specifically, so I wonder if it used to be for an older version of tools but they've fixed it?  But again, I can't seem to find any mention...